# Transfer user defaults across .swift files

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I want to set the user defaults in an app utility file and call them in any view controller I want. Here is a today widget:

```
import UIKit
import NotificationCenter

class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {

@IBOutlet weak var BitCount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var upCost: UILabel!

var Bits:Double = defualts.double(forKey: "bits")
var bitsPerClick:Double = defualts.double(forKey: "bitsPerClick")
var upgradePrice:Double =  defualts.double(forKey: "upgradeCost")

//Click bit
@IBAction func Click(_ sender: Any) {
    AppUtility().bitClick()
    BitCount.text = "\(Bits)"
}

//Click Upgrade
@IBAction func Upgrade(_ sender: Any) {
    AppUtility().upgradeClick()
        upCost.text = "Cost \(upgradePrice)"
        BitCount.text = "\(Bits)"
}
```

Here is the app utility:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let defualts = UserDefaults.standard

var Bits:Double = defualts.double(forKey: "bits")
var bitsPerClick:Double = defualts.double(forKey: "bitsPerClick")
var upgradePrice:Double =  defualts.double(forKey: "upgradeCost")

class AppUtility: UIViewController {

public func setDefualts() {
defualts.set(0, forKey: "bits")

defualts.set(1, forKey: "bitsPerClick")

defualts.set(10, forKey: "upgradeCost")
}

public func upgradeClick() {

    if Bits >= upgradePrice {
        Bits = Bits - upgradePrice
        bitsPerClick = bitsPerClick + 1
        upgradePrice = upgradePrice * 1.5
    }
}
public func bitClick() {
    Bits = Bits + bitsPerClick
}
}
```

When I run the code all of my labels show up blank so I assume that the user defaults are either not set or not called properly

Answer (score 1):

You store your values as integers but reads them as doubles.

Change

```
 defualts.set(1, forKey: "bitsPerClick")
```

to

```
 defualts.set(1.0, forKey: "bitsPerClick")
```

*or* read them as integers

```
var bitsPerClick:Int = defualts.integer(forKey: "bitsPerClick")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/// Global Struct
struct globalValues {
    static var firstValue : String?
    static var secondValue : String?
}

/// Set Value
globalValues.firstValue = "1"
globalValues.secondValue = "2"

/// Get Values
print(globalValues.firstValue ?? "")
print(globalValues.secondValue ?? "")

/// When App is closed Struct will be cleared
/// Save Data for reference in UserDefaults
/// Now in App Delegate which is called for
/// first time Just Assign
/// Userdefaults values to Struct
/// So you can use it -- like
globalValues.firstValue = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "firstValue") as? String
globalValues.secondValue = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "secondValue") as? String
```

So, You are not required to pass anything from one class to another, which will save your time and some amount of code (compiling time)